# Connect TextView with code inside a UITableView Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, textview

I am developing an application in Xcode using objective-c. My problem is that I want to connect a TextView called `phoneTextView` with the code but Xcode said me "Illegal Configuration: The phoneTextView outlet from the RestViewController to the UITextView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" I have a UIViewController called `RestViewController` and inside the UIViewController I have a TableView. Inside this TableView is where I want to put my TextView in the cell.

The TextView should change depending on the `TitleLabel` as you can see in the `RestViewController.m`.

There is any way to doing it?

This is my RestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Restaurant.h"

@interface RestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *headerImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *phoneTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *webButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *DetailModal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

This is my RestViewController.m:

```
    #import "RestViewController.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
    #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
    #import "RestDetailsTableViewCell.h"

    @interface RestViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation RestViewController {
        NSArray *cellsIdentifier;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *decDate = @"12/2016";

        self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.myTableView.delegate = self;

        cellsIdentifier = @[@"first", @"second", @"third", @"fourth"];

        self.myTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]; /*Esta linea hace que en la tabla solo aparezcan el numero de filas que tienes establecidas, es decir, que las vacias no aparezcan*/


        _ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        _ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        _ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        if ([_DetailModal.title isEqualToString:@"80 Grados"]) {
            _headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"80_grados_head.jpg"];
            _TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal.title;
            _DescriptionLabel.text = _DetailModal.desc;
            _ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_DetailModal.image];
            _phoneTextView.text = @"(+34) 914 458 351";
            _adressTextView.text = @"\n• Calle Manuela Malasaña, 10, Madrid, España";
        }

        if ([_DetailModal.title isEqualToString:@"90 Grados"]) {
            _headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"90_grados_head.jpg"];
            _TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal.title;
            _DescriptionLabel.text = _DetailModal.desc;
            _ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_DetailModal.image];
            _phoneTextView.text = @"(+34) 91 573 28 21";
            _adressTextView.text = @"\n• Calle del Alcalde Sainz de Baranda, 64, Madrid, España";
        }
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [cellsIdentifier count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier  = [cellsIdentifier objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...
cell.phoneDetTextView.text = _phoneTextView.text;

        return cell;
    }

    @end
```

This is my RestDetailsTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RestDetailsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *phoneDetTextView;

@end
```

This is my Main.storyboard:

[image]

I am starting in Xcode and I know that I have a low level but I am trying to improve every day. Thank you very much for all responses!

Comment: You should connect textview's outlet in your custom cell class and also set the textview's text as `cell.phoneTextView.text = " "` in cellforrow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated my answer changing the name of the textView in the `RestDetailsTableViewCell.h`. Also, I've updated the cellforrow... method. And finally I´ve connected the `phoneDetTextView`in the `RestDetailsTableViewCell.h`with the textView in the Main.storyboard, but Xcode is showing me a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". I don't know what is wrong. Can you help me @NikhilManapure? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *phoneTextView;` in your controller?

Comment: Whatever you put in cell should have outlets in your `UITableView` subclass and no where else. And you should access only from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods.